# why the Route::resource() does not update the routes after deleting/updating the name some methods in the controller

Tags: laravel

i created a controller with php artisan make:Controller foo --resource 
and i deleted some methods an change the name of the update method to updatePreferenceCompte but when i exec the comm php artisan route:list
the routes remain the same and sry for my english

**ComptesController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ComptesController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function updatePreferenceCompte(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@tableau_bord');
Route::get('/quittances', 'PagesController@quittances');
Route::get('/profil', 'PagesController@profil');
Route::resource('compte', 'ComptesController');


Auth::routes();
```

php artisan route:list
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Route::resource()` results with some predefined routes:

Example with `Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController')`, `route:list` output'd contain:

```
Verb        URI                    Action       Route Name
GET         /photos                index        photos.index
GET         /photos/create         create       photos.create
POST        /photos                store        photos.store
GET         /photos/{photo}        show         photos.show
GET         /photos/{photo}/edit   edit         photos.edit
PUT/PATCH   /photos/{photo}        update       photos.update
DELETE      /photos/{photo}        destroy      photos.destroy
```

[Documentation link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers)

If you want to **leave only some of resource routes**, use *Partial Resource Routes*:

```
Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController')->only([
    'index', 'show'
]);
```

results in

```
Verb        URI                    Action       Route Name
GET         /photos                index        photos.index
GET         /photos/{photo}        show         photos.show
```

and

```
Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController')->except([
    'create', 'store', 'update', 'destroy'
]);
```

results in

```
Verb        URI                    Action       Route Name
GET         /photos                index        photos.index
GET         /photos/{photo}        show         photos.show
GET         /photos/{photo}/edit   edit         photos.edit
```

Comment: ok what about change the name of a method example edit to editComptes?

Comment: You need to define it by hands. Please, read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes)

Answer (score 0):

Can you run `php artisan route:list` 
and paste the results here. 
Try clearing cache `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: updated and the com php artisan config:cache did not work

Comment: can you be more specific what you are trying to do here